# How are Adorners implemented in UWP?

Tags: wpf, uwp

How are adorners implement in UWP apps? If they are implemented the same as in standard WPF what is the namespace / assembly that should be used?

Comment: Do you mean the [Adorner framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.110).aspx) in WPF?

Comment: Something like that yes.  The WPF Adorner framework uses namespaces that I am unable to find in my UWP app.

Answer (score 8):

[Adorners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.110).aspx) are not implemented in UWP.

> An [Adorner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adorner(v=vs.110).aspx) is a custom [FrameworkElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement(v=vs.110).aspx) that is bound to a [UIElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement(v=vs.110).aspx). Adorners are rendered in an [AdornerLayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerlayer(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a rendering surface that is always on top of the adorned element or a collection of adorned elements. Rendering of an adorner is independent from rendering of the [UIElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement(v=vs.110).aspx) that the adorner is bound to. An adorner is typically positioned relative to the element to which it is bound, using the standard 2-D coordinate origin located at the upper-left of the adorned element.

However, [AdornerLayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerlayer(v=vs.110).aspx) is not existed in UWP, we can't use [Adorner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adorner(v=vs.110).aspx) in UWP apps. One alternative way in UWP might be using [**Popup**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842). [Popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842) is a general purpose container for hosting [UIElements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement) on top of existing content. Similar to [Adorner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adorner(v=vs.110).aspx), [Popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842) is rendered in **PopupRoot**, which is a layer that is always on top of other elements.

For more info, please see [An alternative way to create Adorner Layers in Windows 8 App](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2770998). Although this article is written for Windows 8 Apps, but it should also work in UWP apps.